# How to deep dive into HTML from a PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: powershell

There is a website without a easy-to-process feed (no feed at all). I need to retrieve information from that website and convert the information into another format.

The website has some HTML tables with ids.

```
<table id="category1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Date/Time</td>
      <td>Event</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,a1">2018-04-19 13:05</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,a1">Create Stackoverflow post draft</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,b2">2018-04-19 13:07</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,b2">Extend Stackoverflow post draft with code examples</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="category2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Date/Time</td>
      <td>Event</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,c3">2018-04-19 13:09</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,c3">Extend Stackoverflow post draft code examples with second table</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,d4">2018-04-19 13:10</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://www.example.com/event,d4">Finishing Stackoverflow post draft code examples</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The tables' id represent a *event category*. I also need to keep track of this event category information.

The end result should be like the following JSON representation:

```
[
  {
    "id": "a1"
    "timestamp": "2018-04-19T13:05:01+0200",
    "headline": "Create Stackoverflow post draft",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/event,a1",
    "category": "category1"
  },
  {
    "id": "b2"
    "timestamp": "2018-04-19T13:07:02+0200",
    "headline": "Extend Stackoverflow post draft with code examples",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/event,b2",
    "category": "category1"
  },
  {
    "id": "c3"
    "timestamp": "2018-04-19T13:09:03+0200",
    "headline": "Extend Stackoverflow post draft code examples with second table",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/event,c3",
    "category": "category2"
  },
  {
    "id": "d4"
    "timestamp": "2018-04-19T13:10:03+0200",
    "headline": "Finishing Stackoverflow post draft code examples",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/event,d4",
    "category": "category2"
  }
]
```

The *id* is the part from the `a` link tag, which comes after `event,`.

I wrote a quick PoC:

```
$PSVersion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
$Website = Invoke-WebRequest -UserAgent "EventParser PowerShell/$PSVersion" -Method Get "http://www.example.com/events/"
$Category1 = $Website.AllElements | Where { $_.tagName -eq "table" } | Where { $_.id -eq "category1" }
$Category2 = $Website.AllElements | Where { $_.tagName -eq "table" } | Where { $_.id -eq "category2" }
```

Now I have the two distinct tables in two distinct variables (`$Category1` and `$Category2`).

The issue now is, that I have no clue how to iterate over the *second* `tr` till the end of the table.

First `$website` was an *HtmlWebResponseObject*, which is pretty nice to handle.
However after selecting the tables using `Where` statements, I am left with *PSCustomObject* objects. I tried to parse the `innerHTML` with *HTMLFile* ComObject but could not get managed to dive further into to extract the required information.

**How to parse the HTML table snippets to retrieve the information with PowerShell?**

Comment: I would advice you to have a look at HTMLAgilityPack where you can use XPATH to select what you need. This is by far my preferred method for doing stuff like this. Recently Chrome has added the "copy as XPATH" option in their Developer-tools to make these kind of tasks really easy,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when scraping web sites you don't own, a HTML parser should be used. However, if the `HTML` from the website **is as consistently formatted as your example above**, you can iterate over all the elements returned from the response:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UserAgent "EventParser PowerShell/$PSVersion" -Method Get $website;
$results = @{};
$currentCategory = $null;
$currentHref = $null;
foreach ($e in $response.AllElements) {
    switch ($e.tagName) { 
        'table' {
            $currentCategory = $e.id;
        }
        'tr' {
            $currentHref = $null;
        }
        'a' {
            $href, $id = [Regex]::Split($e.href, '\s*,\s*', 2);
            if ($href -ne $null -and $id -ne $null) {
                if ($currentHref -eq $null) { 
                    $currentHref = $href;
                    $results.$id = @{};
                    $results.$id.'id' = $id;               
                    $results.$id.'category' = $currentCategory;
                    $results.$id.'link' = $currentHref;
                }
                if ($e.innerText -match '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}') {
                    $results.$id.'timestamp' = $e.innerText;
                } else {
                    $results.$id.'headline' = $e.innerText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Tested and working with your HTML sample above*.

Then dump the results like this:

```
$array = @();
$results.Keys | foreach { $array += $results.$_; };
$array | ConvertTo-Json;
```